# How to produce a click/tap with code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a facial recognition feature that will produce a click/tap when the user blinks. Is there a way to "produce" the click with the code? It doesn't look like I can use onMouseDown or Button.onClick since there is no button or a mouse. 
Essentially what I have is:

```
public void Blink(){
*code that lets the computer know that user blinked* }
```

What I need to add is:

```
public void ClickedByBlinking(){
*some code to producer a click (Blink) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp)
https://answers.unity.com/questions/564664/how-i-can-move-mouse-cursor-without-mouse-but-with.html Instead of using the keybord use the blink.